# Proof of Frobenius' $p$-nilpotency criterion

Tags: gr.group-theory, finite-groups

Can anyone suggest a proof of Frobenius' $p$-nilpotency criterion (i.e. $N_G(H)/C_G(H)$ is a $p$-group for every non-trivial $p$-subgroup $H$ of $G$) that does not run through Alperin's results on fusion?  I presume the former predates the latter by five or six decades, but the only proof I've seen is the one in Gorenstein's *Finite Groups*.  Of course one has to start somewhere, so feel free to use basic results on the transfer map $\tau$ of a group $G$ into a $p$-Sylow subgroup $P$, e.g. $P\cap G'(p) = P\cap G' = P\cap \ker{\tau}$, Burnside's $p$-complement theorem, and Grün's theorems.

Comment: Check out Theorems 4.2.5 and 14.4.7 in "The Theory of Groups" by Marshall Hall, Jr., Macmillan Co., 1959.

Comment: That works for me.  Thanks @RichardLyons!

Comment: You can also find this in Isaacs' book on Finite Group Theory - it's Theorem 5.26.

Comment: See also Robinson's "A course in the theory of groups".